# How to make custom button in Roku?

Tags: user-interface, roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I want to make this type of button in Roku, If you have any information let me know. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an XML file for your custom component. You can extend "Group" to make custom buttons. https://developer.roku.com/docs/developer-program/core-concepts/xml-components/creating-custom-components.md

In your custom component, you'll want child nodes rectangle and label. You'll want to set "focusable" to true. and a custom field aliased to the label's text. You will want to include a companion "brs" file (or the code directly in XML) to observe "focusedChild" and show a focus effect when the button gains focus. that's about it!